# what is the meaning of public PictureBox[] pictureb => Controls.OfType<PictureBox>().ToArray();

Tags: c#, winforms

Does "`PictureBox[] pictureb =>` "code mean using pictureb as a get method with picturebox array type. `Controls.OfType<PictureBox>().ToArray();` means control properties using oftype which is ienumerable method convert to array.

Answer (score 2):

Let's break down your code

`public PictureBox[] pictureb => Controls.OfType<PictureBox>().ToArray();`

into smaller manageable pieces.

If you were to declare a read-only property in - say C# 3.0 - you would use syntax similar to this.

```
public PictureBox[] picture
{
    get
    {
         /* Some code which returns a PictureBox array. */
    }
}
```

C# 6.0 - I believe added expression bodied members. So we can abbreviate the above code somewhat with this syntax.

`public PictureBox[] pictureb => Controls.OfType<PictureBox>().ToArray();`

The portion after `=>` is the body of this property, which is `Controls.OfType<PictureBox>().ToArray();` in this case.

Comment: can i interpret that as picture is a property which return type is array picturebox  that return this (Controls.OfType<PictureBox>().ToArray();)

Comment: Mostly correct, except that it returns `PictureBox[]`. The body is **how** it gets the array, it is executed not returned. You need to improve your terminology.

Comment: @Gerald  It's a syntax evolution of the standard `get` method you see here. You can also have `public PictureBox[] picture { get => Controls.OfType<PictureBox>().ToArray(); } `, which  can then be *shrinked* to `public PictureBox[] picture => Controls.OfType<PictureBox>().ToArray();`.

Comment: That's not in chronological order @Jimi.

Comment: No, it wasn't meant to be. The `expression body property accessor` requires C# 6, the `expression-bodied property` (the one in the question) requires C# 5. All *syntactic sugar* (as usually referred to), over the same property accessors methods, which remain the same under the hood.